# VS2013 IDE: Highlighted reference bug

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

I've encountered a strange issue in visual studio.

**When clicking on an item where there are other/similarly name references on the page.**
[image]

**After hovering/clicking on one of the other references, things seem to revert to normal.**
[image]

A bit more research onto the topic and I found this.

> [highlighted reference bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/533626/highlighted-reference-foreground-color-in-fonts-colors-not-working)

Has anyone encountered this. And do you know how to fix this... As is super annoying :/ And it doesn't look like this issue is resolved based on the post..

I'm using VS2013 Update 2, and a monokai colour scheme.

**To clarify this visual anomaly:**

If you look in the first image, I've selected the Id value inside the *agreementService.Approve* call. I'm expecting all the other Id values on screen to be highlighted with the same colour, but they aren't.

Comment: Err, what is the issue, exactly? In the first picture, all of the snippets that contain `id` are highlighted. In the second picture, all of the snippets that contain `agreementFilterService` are highlighted. It seems to be working as advertised.

Comment: In first set of highlights (Id) the highlight colour isn't the one that is applied in the settings. Either that or the font isn't switched to the appropriate colour to make it easily readable. It's a slight difference, but enough to be super annoying...

Comment: Hmm yeah, I see. I thought you had just selected a poor highlighted reference color. I guess the second example does have slightly better contrast. Do you have any extensions installed that are providing similar highlighting functionality, and potentially conflicting with the built-in stuff? Try running VS in safe mode and see if you can repro the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found a console command to reset my settings.

> "devenv.exe /ResetSettings".

Prob could have done this through the settings interface somehow as well.

It ended up resetting everything, and all I had to do was a re-import of the font & colours as well as my other settings, eg. ReSharper etc. Which I backed up before hand.

Seemed to solve the glitch